# PHP&MySQL Updating table not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I'm trying to do a simple MySQL Database/Table update, but something isn't working and I can't figure out what. I'll put the code:
morepoints.php (handles the addition of points):

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["name"]))
{
    echo "<a href='index.php'>Username/points cookie not existent! Please login!</a>";
}
$con=mysql_connect("sqlserverip","name","password");
if(!$con)
{
    echo "Error while connecting to the MySQL server: " . mysql_error();
}
mysql_select_db("gendb1",$con);
$name=$_COOKIE["name"];
$pts=$_COOKIE["points"];
mysql_query("UPDATE  \"users\"  SET  \"pts\" =\"" . $pts . "\" WHERE name=\"" . $name . "\"");
echo "<div id='wrapper'>Updated database...checking if values match...</div>";
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
 {
            if($row["name"]==$name)
            {
                if($row["pts"]==$pts)
                {
                    echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Points awarded! Please login again.</a>";
                    mysql_close($con);
                }
            }
  } 
    ?>
```

And in case you want the login page where the cookies are set, here it is

```
    <?php
$con=mysql_connect("mysqlserverip","name","password");
if(!$con)
{
    echo "Connection to the MySQL server failed successfuly! " . mysql_error();
}
mysql_select_db("gendb1",$con);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

//Getting Login Form Data
$name=$_POST['u'];
$pass=$_POST['p']; 
$points;
//$valid=1;
if($name=="" or $pass=="")
{
    echo "<div id=\"wrapper\">Name/pass cannot be blank. <a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">Try again</a></div>";
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['name']==$name and $row['pass']==$pass)
    {
        setcookie("name",$row['name'],time()+300);
        setcookie("points",$row['pts'],time()+300);
        echo "<div id=\"wrapper\">Login successful! <a href=\"user.php\">Go to your page</a></div>";
        goto done;
        break;
    }
}
echo "<script>history.go(-1);</script>";
done:
    ?>
```

SOLVED: What I'm getting is an HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error with error code: 0x00000000
I usually get that when the PHP code can't be interpreted (or whatever) due to some error in my srcipting
STILL: Database/Table is not updating (No error is thrown when I run the script but the DB doesn't seem to be updating)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query`? Is this part of a legacy project or a new application?

Comment: FreshPrinceOfSO thanks for the tip and tadman: It's sort of a weekend project. PHP is more of a hobby right now

Comment: Doing PHP this way is really difficult and error-prone. Even for hobby projects, or I might even say *especially* for those, you probably want to use a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) as a foundation. A good framework will save you a ton of time, effort and frustration. Further, `mysql_query` is being removed from PHP, it's a terrible interface to MySQL. [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is the best alternative to that.

Comment: Did you read my answer below ?! It should at least show you why it's not updating, if no PHP errors are arising. Ow and when are you actually raising $pts / $points ? It seems you don't increment it at all. All you say is `$pts=$_COOKIE["points"];` in one script and merely `$points;` in the other script. Shouldn't there at least be `$pts++;` somewhere in the first script???

Answer (score 2):

- Use backticks (`) instead of quotes (") to specify database/table/column names.
  I have seen this answer before in this thread, but it was deleted. Though it is a correct answer.
- Also escape your input to prevent sql injection. And check to see if the query ran fine.
- And lastly check if the query was executed ok.

So change

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  \"users\"  SET  \"pts\" =\"" . $pts . "\" WHERE name=\"" . $name . "\"");
```

into

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `users`  SET  `pts` =\"" . mysql_real_escape_string($pts) . "\" WHERE `name`=\"" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "\"")
    or die ("Update failed: " . mysql_error() );
```

The last part will output the error message if the query failed. (Notice I removed the semi-colon (;) at the end of the first line so the "or die" is part of the same sentence.

- **edit**
  Are you actually raising $pts / $points ? It seems you don't increment it at all. All you say is `$pts=$_COOKIE["points"];` in one script and merely `$points;` in the other script. Shouldn't there at least be `$pts++;` somewhere in the first script??? (After settings $pts and before running the update query.)

Comment: Well, you're right... I thought I had set the points cookie to the new ammount (The ammount of points to be added is submitted in another page)

Comment: @user2246174 so is this why you thought the db was not updating? because it was updating to the old values?

Answer (score 1):

In the first script you'r missing ")" closing **while** sentence:

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"));
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result){

Comment: Oh...I just noticed that..I'll see if that's the problem

Comment: Yup, that was it! It fixed the 500 Error but the DB is still not updating(maybe I need to give it some time but...dunno)

Comment: Ah, you just updated your question and added the error 500. First you said only the update query didn't work. In this case you should have checked your php_error log file.

Comment: @alex-abreu-mulet Why is `and` not ok? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php I think it is valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

What error/problem is happening? When dealing with MYSQL updates, it is always a good idea to try echoing out the MYSQL call, such as:

```
$test_call = "UPDATE  \"users\"  SET  \"pts\" =\"" . $pts . "\" WHERE name=\"" . $name . "\"");

echo $test_call;
```

That way you can see exactly what is being sent to MYSQL, and can try the result out in something like phpMyAdmin or MYSQL Query Browser.  Will help to narrow down the problem.

Also, you can make that same update a bit easier by using single quotes, like so:

```
$pts = mysql_real_escape_string($pts);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
"UPDATE `users`  SET  `pts` = '$pts' WHERE `name` = '$name'"
```

Comment: This does not have any escaping.

Comment: What would you use then tadman?  The main point of mine was meant to be echoing out the statement and then testing it for accuracy.

Comment: you need to change $name into '$name' in your answer

Comment: Good catch, and done.  I'm still not clear though on why it needs escaping?

Comment: If you're using `mysql_query`, then you **must** use `mysql_real_escape_string` on any and all values put into the query string. Yes, this is annoying. No, you do not get to skip this step. If you don't understand why, you really need to read up on [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).